# ¿Por qué asigna vació una variable de sqlserver cuando esta en un cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy probando una consulta con un curso, quería asegurarme que estuviera pasando el campo de la tabla al curso, pero me estoy dando cuenta que cuando ya esta dentro del cursor la variable que imprime esta vacía.

Esta es la consulta de la tabla donde voy hacer el cursor y el resultado de la misma

[image: consulta]
[image: resultado consulta]

Esta es la consulta del cursor y el resulta del mismo

```
DECLARE @userName nvarchar(25)
DECLARE movements CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    TOP 3 
    syM.DSCreateUser
FROM
    SY_Movement AS syM
WHERE
    syM.PostedDTS = DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
OPEN movements
FETCH NEXT FROM movements INTO @userName
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            tblE.vchSupervisorName,@userName,LEN(@userName)
        FROM 
            [MXCHIM0SQLV03A].[Kronos_Interfaces].[dbo].[tblEmployees] AS tblE
        WHERE
            tblE.vchUserName = @userName
    END
FETCH NEXT FROM movements INTO @userName
END
CLOSE movements;
DEALLOCATE movements;
```

[image: resultado consulta]

Como vemos no no imprime o no lee el nombre de usuario `SCHED_D_GL`, alguien sabe porque hace eso el cursor, de antemano gracias.

Ya realice el inner join de las dos tablas, pero me sale este error:

```
SELECT
TOP 10
    syM.DSCreateUser
FROM
    SY_Movement AS syM
    INNER JOIN [MXCHIM0SQLV03A].[Kronos_Interfaces].[dbo].[tblEmployees] AS tblE ON syM.DSCreateUser = tblE.vchUserName
WHERE
syM.PostedDTS = DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()))
ORDER BY syM.PKMovement
    

Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 35
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

Me fije que el campo DSCreateUser de la tabla SY_Movement es nvarchar(25) y el campo vchUserName de la tabla [tblEmployees] es nvarchar(50)
[tblEmployees]

Comment: En realidad no veo nada incorrecto con tu cursor, ni tampoco es obvio para nosotros que los datos son incorrectos. Tal vez esos 2 valores para `DSCreateUser` no existen en la tabla `tblEmployees`. Para hacer una comparación mas significativa, muestranos el resultado de hacer una consulta que hace un join entre `SY_Movement` y `tblEmployees`. Allí se podrá ver más claramente si hay algo que no va con el cursor. Pero para mi, es algo con tus datos simplemente. Adicionalmente, espero que esto sea solo una prueba y que no vayas a usar el cursor de verdad, porque no hay necesidad de un cursor aquí.

Comment: Un detalle más a tomar en cuenta: Sin un `ORDER BY` en tu consulta con el `TOP 3`, no hay garantía que siempre obtengas los mismos 3 resultados. Esto también pudiera causarte problemas.

Comment: voy a realizar la consulta que me dices

Comment: Ok, pero con un `ORDER BY` para evitar sorpresas, ok?

Comment: Ya realice la consulta

Comment: Hmm. Ese error que recibes puede ser la explicación del porqué no recibes resultados en algunos casos. Puede que la tabla `tblEmployees` esté configurada con un collation que hace que las diferencias en mayúscula y minúscula sean significativas.  ¿Puedes volver a probar el código con tu cursor, pero en vez de `WHERE tblE.vchUserName = @userName`, intenta `WHERE tblE.vchUserName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = @userName`?

Comment: Ya quedo gracias :D

Comment: ¿Agregar el `collate` al `where` resolvió el problema por sí solo? ¿O tuvistes que hacer otra cosa?

Comment: Asi es @sstan, gracias !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a que cuando hicistes la prueba de hacer un join entre las 2 tablas recibistes el error siguiente:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

...esto dio indicación de que, al menos la columna `vchUserName` de la tabla `tblEmployees`, estaba usando el `COLLATE` `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.  El `CS` significa `Case Sensitive`. O sea que cuando comparas una cadena con esa columna, las diferencias en mayúsculas y minúsculas son significativas.

Cuando te pedí de modificar el `WHERE` a:

```
WHERE tblE.vchUserName collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = @userName
```

... me indicastes que esto arregló el problema.

La razón por la que esto arregló el problema es porque al especificar que la condición debía usar `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (Case Insensitive), entonces las diferencias de mayúsculas y minúsculas ya no se tomaban en cuenta al evaluar la condición.

O sea que, en resumen, tu problema era simplemente que los datos de ambas tablas sí tenían diferencias de mayúsculas y minúsculas, y por esto la comparación fallaba, porque consideraba que esas diferencias eran significativas.